# Sessão do CodeIgniter expira rápido

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Fiz um painel de controle para um cliente e nesse painel o meu cliente pode editar os produtos do site. Após o cliente **Editar** um produto e clicar em **Salvar**, quando o cliente vai tentar editar mais campos o sistema redireciona para a página de login, ou seja, a sessão expira, pois quando não existe uma sessão o sistema redireciona para a página de login. As vezes o cliente navegando no painel de controle, em pouco mais de 2 minutos ele redireciona para a página de login. Abaixo as configurações da sessão do arquivo `application/config.php`

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 86400;
```

Answer (score 1):

No arquivo de configuração existe uma parte para configurar as variáveis de sessão.

Nessa parte você encontra a configuração

```
$config['sess_expiration']
```

Essa variável serve para setar o tempo, em segundos, que sua sessão deve durar. Set essa variável para zero e a sessão vai durar até o navegador fechar.

Answer (score 0):

Tente definir a sessão para um número muito grande, ao invés de usar zero. Tente:

```
time()+(3600*24*365*5)
```

ou

```
time()+157680000;
```

Essa sessão deve durar cerca de 5 anos.